# Upper Bound on $\frac{1+ax^{n+1}}{1+ax^n}$ for $x \in (0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, upper-lower-bounds

I am looking for an upper bound on
$$\frac{1+ax^{n+1}}{1+ax^n}$$
in the regime $x \in (0,1)$  where $a>0$ and $n$ is a non-negative integer.

I would like it to be of the form
\begin{align}
\frac{1+ax^{n+1}}{1+ax^n} \le f(a,x,n)
\end{align}
where $f(a,x,n)$ is a polynomial. Moreover, I would like to be `good' around $x=1$.

Clearly, there is a trivial bound
\begin{align}
\frac{1+ax^{n+1}}{1+ax^n} \le 1. 
\end{align}

I was thinking that we can do a Tailor expansion around the minimum of this function.

Comment: Are you looking for a global upper bound (which is $1$) or a function $f$ such that $(1+ax^{n+1})/(1+a x^n) \le f(x,a,n) \forall x\in(0,1)$? If the latter, is there a particular form you'd like $f$ to have?

Comment: I am looking for a function $f(x,a,n)$. I will add this clerfication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the following polynomial upper bound:
\begin{align}
\frac{1+ax^{n+1}}{1+ax^n} &= \frac{1+ax^n - ax^n + ax^{n+1}}{1+ax^n} \\
&= 1 - \frac{ax^n(1-x)}{1+ax^n}\\
&\le 1 - \frac{ax^n}{(1+a)^2}(1+2a - ax^n)(1-x)
\end{align}
where we have used
$$\frac{1}{1+ax^n} = \frac{1}{1+a}\cdot\frac{1}{1 - \frac{a(1-x^n)}{1+a}}
\ge \frac{1}{1+a}\left(1 + \frac{a(1-x^n)}{1+a}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you. This bound is very good for $x$ close to zero but is not very good around $x=1$. Do you think your approach can be used to find a bound that is good around $x=1$?

Comment: @Lisa Yes, it is bad around $x=1$. Let me think about it.

Comment: Thank you. Please don't delete this answer.  I think what you did is also useful.

Comment: @Lisa  I updated my result.

Answer (score 4):

The trivial bound is the best you can do, because $$\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1+ax^{n+1}}{1+ax^n} = 1.$$

Comment: But can't we find an upper bound that is tight at $x=1$?

Answer (score 2):

If we Taylor expand the function around $x=1$, we have
$$\frac{1+a\,x^{n+1}}{1+a\,x^n}=1+t+\frac{n }{a}t^2+O\left(t^3\right)\qquad \text{where} \qquad t=-\frac{a (1-x)}{a+1}$$

Hoping that it could help !